# The operator $T_A\colon H \to AH+HA$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $H$ be $n \times n$ matrices, consider the operator $T_A$ such that $T_A(H)=AH+HA$. How to show this operator is invertible?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please take a look at [how to format mathematics here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: You cannot. E.g. when $A=0$, $T_A$ is the zero operator, which is not invertible unless $n\le1$.

Comment: @user1551 $T_{O_n}$ is not invertible even for $n = 1$. Maybe matrix $A$ is nondegenerate?

Comment: @Smylic You are right. $T_0$ isn't invertible unless $n=0$.

Comment: @user1551 $n = 0$ is the most useful case possible.

Comment: You need to actually try to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Anyway, I think this has been asked before. As the matrix of $T_A$ is $A^T\otimes I+I\otimes A$ and $A^T$ is similar to $A$, the eigenvalues of $T_A$ are $\lambda_i+\lambda_j$ for every $\lambda_i,\lambda_j$ in the spectrum of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

See the Wikipedia entry for the [Sylvester Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) for more information.

The operator $T_A$ is invertible if and only if $A$ does not have a pair of eigenvalues whose sum is $0$ (in particular $A$ needs to be invertible). To see this, write the equation

$$X = AH + HA$$

in terms of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) as

$$\mathrm{vec}(X) = (I \otimes A + A^T \otimes I)\mathrm{vec}(H).$$

As you can see, $T_A$ is invertible if and only if the matrix $I \otimes A + A^T \otimes I$ is invertible. Note that in general, the eigenvalues of $I \otimes A + B \otimes I$ are of the form $\lambda + \mu$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.

The condition we gave on the eigenvalues of $A$ tell us that $I \otimes A + A^T \otimes I$ does not have $0$ as an eigenvalue. Therefore it and hence $T_A$ are invertible.

Comment: When you say a pair of eigenvalues whose sum is zero, you are allowing repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, if the $n$ eigenvalues of $A$ (with multiplicity) are $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ then the $n^2$ eigenvalues of $I \otimes A + A^T \otimes I$ are $\lambda_i + \lambda_j : i, j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$. In particular, if $A$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue then $I \otimes A + A^T \otimes I$ has $0 + 0$ as an eigenvalue.